# Code not appending the correct object... Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my code to take a coordinate, turn that location on the board to a player token (i.e. 1), and then turn any other token that is thusly enclosed by two player tokens also into a player token.

Then I want it to append the board to a list (boardlist1). 
This process should then be repeated for the second coordinate and in my boardlist1 I should get back 2 different boards.

However: I get back 2 identical boards. Help would be apprectiated.

```
import numpy

board = numpy.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])



boardlist0 = [board]*len([[5,3], [3,5]])

boardlist1 = []
ind = 0



for k in [[5,3], [3,5]]:

    boardlist0[ind][k[0]][k[1]] = 1

    direction = [[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [0,-1], [-1,0], [-1,-1], [1,-1], [-1,1]]
    coord = []


    for j in direction:
        O1 = k[0]
        O2 = k[1]
        k[1] = k[1] + j[1]
        k[0] = k[0] + j[0]
        if k[0] > 7 or k[0] < 0 or k[1] > 7 or k[1] < 0:
                k[1] = k[1] - j[1]
                k[0] = k[0] - j[0]
        while boardlist0[ind][k[0]][k[1]] == 2:
            coord.append(k)                   
            k[1] = k[1] + j[1]
            k[0] = k[0] + j[0]
            if k[0] > 7 or k[0] < 0 or k[1] > 7 or k[1] < 0:
                k[1] = k[1] - j[1]
                k[0] = k[0] - j[0]
                coord = []
                break
            if boardlist0[ind][k[0]][k[1]] == 0:
                coord = []
                break
            elif boardlist0[ind][k[0]][k[1]] == 1:
                for i in coord:
                    boardlist0[ind][i[0] - j[0]][i[1] - j[1]] = 1
                boardlist1.append(boardlist0[ind])                    

        k[0] = O1
        k[1] = O2
    ind += 1



print boardlist1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boardlist0= [board]*len( [[5,3], [3,5]] )

Returns a list containing  two references to the *same* `array` object, so modifying the array elements via `boardlist[0]` also changes `boardlist[1]` (and vice versa).

This is an important thing to keep in mind when doing list initialization of mutable objects, including `numpy.array`'s, `list`'s, `dict`'s etc.  `[obj]*N` gives `N` a list of `N` references to the same object; for immutable things (numbers, strings, tuples) this will almost always do what you want.

A way to resolve this is to explicitly copy the arrays, e.g.:

```
[board.copy() for i in xrange( len( [[5,3],[3,5]] )) ]
```

There is also a `numpy.copy` copy if you prefer to write it more like `numpy.copy(board)`.

If you are not wedded to the "list of boards" design, you could make the entire structure into a single `numpy` array:

```
boardlist0=numpy.repeat( board[numpy.newaxis,:,:], len([[5,3],[3,5]]), axis=0)
```

and then index it via `boardlist0[ind,k[0],k[1]]`

Comment: Do you maybe have a suggestion to fix that?

Comment: I tried to get a quick answer in; have just added a way to fix.